# how programmatically execute batch file by another credential

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have tfs local server. I write unit test , that execute batch file. The problem is: when I manual execute batch file it's perfect work. But when this script execute programmatically (check-in unit test and build definition. Test starts on build server by unknown credential) I see half  result. So. How can visual studio (use c#) starts batch file, use credential of another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filenameToStart, username, password, domain);
```

There's also a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643723/c-sharp-and-net-3-5-how-to-launch-a-process-using-different-credentials-with)

And another with a code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624113/how-to-process-start-with-impersonated-domain-user)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue you have, I'd recommend using [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx). So it will be something like:

```
runas.exe /profile /user:YOURDOMAIN\YourUser %yourpath%\yourbatch.bat
```

You can set this to VS to run, instead your batch.
Hope this helps!

Comment: runas need manual password. But I need do this automatically.

Comment: @user3231442 "/savecred" param, if you happen to read the technet link in my answer

Comment: *Enter the user's password only when prompted*